# Install Brother QL700 label printer on Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, brother

I've tried installing QL700 on Lubuntu. In the online instructions which I found, it's mentioned to install driver using CLI.

1. Turn on the printer and connect the USB cable.
2. Click the close button if the installation wizard comes up.
3. Open the terminal and go to the directory where the driver is.
4. Install driver.
   Command :   `dpkg -i --force-all (drivername)`
5. Check if the driver is installed.
   Command :  `dpkg -l | grep Brother`

CLI says I need read/ write permission for dpkg? Can anyone help?

The files I am trying to print are XML files (I don't know if this makes any difference and I've installed OpenOffice instead of the abiword that came pre-loaded.

Also what is the driver name? (I used QL700pdrv.3.1.5-0i386deb)

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided release details (but I'm guessing an old release as `abiword` was replaced by LibreOffice in the last four releases of Lubuntu), but it's best if you provide details rather than us guessing.  How do you know they are XML?  because of filename or you asked the system to tell you (it usually responds with a version too, eg. "*XML 1.0 document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines*"

Comment: XML is the filename I got from looking at the docs I'm trying to print. The release is Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS (hummingbird logo on blue home screen)

Comment: @alg In the comment you've mentioned Ubuntu and in the question you've mentioned Lubuntu. To avoid confusion, we need to find out which Linux distro you have. Open your terminal and paste this command, `cat /etc/os-release`, and press enter. Let me know what the output is.

Comment: I'm convinced the user is on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (an official flavor of Ubuntu 18.04), my question was geared at which release, LXQt or LXDE & then which software stack (HWE or GA, that's all I don't know but currently doesn't matter). I see no QL700 in Ubuntu repositories (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ql700), and you didn't provide details as to where it came from, what instructions you are following (I didn't find any on any Ubuntu site or wiki, and the use of *force* doesn't instill confidence in instructions [more *sloppiness/laziness*])

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

Comment: It was not downloaded from any software stack but from the official Brother website

Comment: Please add additional software to your question; your system is behind on upgrades as it'll report 18.04.5 when fully upgraded *not 18.04.4). It's 3rd party as it came from Brother (isn't Ubuntu software as not from repositories, like any non-Windows software is 3rd party if not from Microsoft).  We can't look up requirements & issues online or via terminal as 3rd party so messages are key to understanding issue, and we can't see them unless provided.